# How to speed up ionic 1 load on sqlite database

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Good day

Am currently working on an ionic 1 application and am experiencing delays in loading data from the database even if its just one item in the database. Can any one please give some advance as how to improve this. I have tried out collection-repeat which is way better in performance but sucks in the appearance as my card still becomes lost after I use it.

Comment: It sounds like the speed issue is with your database and not the app?

Comment: @Chris It could be, I have been checking on line and been hearing its good practice to have db.close at the end at ever transaction. Can this help as currently when I console log my app I see it says db already opened on two occasions.